# Send data to bootstrap modal and perform a mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_from_query)){   
     <a class="modal-trigger" href="#basicModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal" data-id="<?php echo $row['invoice_no']; ?>"><?php echo $row['invoice_no']; ?>
        </a>
}

<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Invoice Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="text" name="invoice" id="invoice" value=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("click", ".modal-trigger", function () {
             var invoiceNO = $(this).data('id');
             $(".modal-body #invoice").val( invoiceNO );
        });
        </script>
```

so i have this code that send data to modal and put it in a `<input name="invoice" />`
now my question is i want to put it in a php variable to use it in a query inside the #basicModal div. 
something like this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Invoice Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <?php 
                             $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT item from invoice_tab where invoice no = ' $invoice_no);
                             $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                             echo $data['item'];
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

but i have no idea on how to put the data in a php variable...can u pls guys help me in this...tnx

Comment: why downvote is there something wrong in my question???

Comment: try using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use your:

```
$row['invoice_no'];
```

in your first example to fill the SQL query in the modal?